# path to image in site collection image library

Tags: 2013, site-collection, site, image

I am adding images to style image collection images through module. Here is my element.xml from my module

```
<Module Name="MyModule" Url="SiteCollectionImages" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
   <File Path="MyModule\test.png" Url="MyImages/test.png" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
</Module>
```

Images are uploaded successfully...

In my master page is trying to refer images are below

```
<img src="< %$ SPUrl: ~sitecollection/sitecollectionimages/MyImages/test.png %>" border="0" />
```

But i get error in console that its internal server error and gives path like this

```
http://myserver/sites/mysite/SitePages/~sitecollection/SiteCollectionImages/MyImages/test.png
```

How exactly to refer this image?

I have put my javascript in style library and referring like this successfully

```
<SharePoint:scriptlink ID="ScriptLink6" runat="server" Name="~sitecollection/Style Library/Intranet/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"/>
```

Why its not picking image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code

```
<img src="<asp:Literal runat='server' Text='<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/sitecollectionimages/MyImages/test.png%>' />" />
```

Comment: oh it worked . why we need to use asp literal control?

Comment: That's great if it works for you. Please mark the answer so others can get benefit of it.

Comment: but why we need to use it like this?

Comment: The Literal Control is similar to the Label Control as they both are used to display static text on a web page & as we have put the SPUrl than it will append the SharePoint URL with this static code. :)

Comment: If you satisfied than please mark it as correct so others can get benefit of it.